# Scrollable div with multiple tables

Tags: jquery, html, css, django

I have a div containing multiple tables with variable number of rows and i would need to make this thing scrollable.

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    {% regroup documents by upload_time|date:" d F o" as documents_by_date %}
    {% for document in documents_by_date %}
    <table style="text-align: left; margin-top: 15px; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <th width="70%">{{ document.grouper}}</th>
        <th align="center"> Uploaded by </th>
    </tr>
    {% for doc in document.list %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ doc.docfile.url }}">{{ doc.filename }}</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            {{doc.upload_user}}
        </td>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

Right now this shows me a scrollbar but it doesnt work. I have almost no experience in html and css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `height` to make it scrollable, otherwise it will take `100%` height and only scrollbar will be shown.

```
 <div style="overflow-y: scroll;height:500px">
     [Omitted for brevity]
 </div>
```

Red more about [Overflow-y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)

Comment: I ll accept it but there must be at least 10 mins apparently

Comment: No problem try after sometime.